# forward open vpn traffic to another port

Tags: iptables, openvpn, ssh-tunnel

I run a openvpn server with port 2030 on my server and run a ssh tunneling on port 2020.
due to there is not authentication method for ssh tunnel (in fact it is a socks connection) I want to route openvpn traffic to ssh tunnel.

scenario:
user connect to openvpn on phone so he is connected to port 2030, at this point I want to route / forward / traffic of openvpn (IP range 10.8.x.x) to my server 2020 port so user traffic must pass through ssh tunnel.

I hope my question good enough to understand.

is any way to do this?

Comment: Does this work? `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 2030 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2020`

Comment: @JoelCrypto no!

Comment: Cant you just allow traffic the port if ip comes from 10.8.x?